# Text added to New window is not visible in Curses

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

I am trying to add a window and a text in this window with curses using [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#windows-and-pads) and this:

```
window.addstr("This is a text in a window")
```

Code:

```
class View:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(True)
        # -----------------
        self.add_window_and_str()
        self.add_str()
        # -----------------
        self.stdscr.getkey()
        curses.endwin()

    def add_str(self): #just text in standart screen
        self.stdscr.addstr("test")
        self.stdscr.refresh()

    def add_window_and_str(self):
        scr_limits = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        win = curses.newwin(scr_limits[0] - 10, scr_limits[1] - 10, 5, 5)
        win.addstr("Example String")
        win.refresh()
        self.stdscr.refresh()
```

The text added with `self.add_str` is visible but the "Example String" is not.
How can i manipulate windows to make that text visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On initialization, the standard screen has a pending update (to clear the screen).  The `refresh` call at the end of `add_window_and_str` does that, overwriting the `win.addstr` output.  You could move that call *before* the first call to `add_window_and_str`.  After that, the changes to `stdscr` would be in parts of the screen outside your window.

There's another problem: calling `getch` refreshes the associated window. Usually programs are organized so that `getch` is associated with whatever window you would like to keep "on top", so that their updates will not be obscured by other windows.  If you return the `win` variable from `add_window_and_str`, you can use that window with `getch`.

Comment: I guess, i need to use panels to make two different things show up together.

Comment: That makes it simpler, but if you keep in mind the way refreshing works in curses, you can make the windows behave as you want, for simple 2-window configurations (adding windows makes it harder).